# Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: iphone, certificate, provisioning, apple-developer

I am attempting to follow the instructions on this page:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW4

To write a Java based test server that will push a payload on the sandbox push service to a test device.

I am an admin on the account, but not the owner.

I have two App IDs.

XXX.cs.* and
XXX.cs.apns

where XXX are the identical 10 character strings that Apple assigns.

Step 2 says I must locate the App ID for the sandbox. And later talks about a configuration button I do not see...

Do I have to create a third App ID for XXX.cs.apnsSandbox or similar?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems only the account owner can configure App IDs and setup the provisioning, thus invalidating my question.

Thanks regardless.